# Chart angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I have some trouble integrating my data json to a chart i tried highlight chart , nvd3 ,google chart i have data  comming out of http get :

```
 $http.get("/get")
.success(function(data){
    $scope.produit=data;
});
```

the result of this is

```
$scope.produit = [
{
    id: 15,
    nom: "azerty",
    type: "azerty",
    quantity: 456,
    prix: 25296
},
{
    id: 21,
    nom: "sdqs",
    type: "qsdqsd",
    quantity: 102,
    prix: 52
}
];
```

i want to view quantity and type in chart i tried to put type and quantity in seprate tables then when i try to use for (i=0;i>$scope.produit.lenght;i++) it won't work because am putting the for inside the data structure of the chart here's an exemple of data structure

```
$scope.pieData = [{

                name: type[0],
                    quantity[0]
                }, {
                    name: "Chrome",
                    y: 24.03,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, {
                    name: "Firefox",
                    y: 10.38
                }, {
                    name: "Safari",
                    y: 4.77
                }, {
                    name: "Opera",
                    y: 0.91
                }, {
                    name: "Proprietary or Undetectable",
                    y: 0.2

                }]
```

Thank you !

Comment: did you find a solution !

Comment: I found a solution using google charts

Comment: Can you please help me and take a look at my question possible you have an idea of my issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056480/how-can-i-get-a-chart-from-a-matrix

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767758/table-has-no-columns-json-data

Comment: that's how i solve it ps i took a look to your question before eveything google chart use anthor data structure in my question there's the solution how you convert your data from json to Google charts data ps someone answered your question and i think it's interesting

Comment: Yes thanks I will check your question and I will back to you as soon as possible thanks for your sharing