# Table has no columns. Json data

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

i have a json data in this format

```
[
{
id: 2,
nom: "Dell",
type: "Pc",
quantity: 78,
prix: 7800
},
{
id: 3,
nom: "Intel",
type: "Processor",
quantity: 45,
prix: 8000
},
{
id: 4,
nom: "Dell",
type: "Ecran",
quantity: 10,
prix: 2500
}
]
```

and i want to put them in a chart help please it's about 4 days and i can't make it work i want to understand why does google chart api don't want to accept this data this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the bar package.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/get",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
      console.log(jsonData)
  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.


  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new    google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the data must be like this:

```
{
    cols: [
        {id: 'task', label: 'Task', type: 'string'},
        {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}
    ],
    rows: [
        {c:[{v: 'Work'}, {v: 11}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Eat'}, {v: 2}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Commute'}, {v: 2}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Watch TV'}, {v:2}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Sleep'}, {v:7, f:'7.000'}]}
    ]
}
```

Take a look to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) and you'll see that you have to define columns in the cols property and the data in the rows property.

So you have to "reformat" your JSON to fit with the requirements.

So for your need of conversion, this code should work:

```
var rows = new Array();

for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++)
{
    var jsonRow = jsonData[i];
    var row = {
        c: [
            {v: jsonRow.id},
            {v: jsonRow.nom},
            {v: jsonRow.type},
            {v: jsonRow.quantity},
            {v: jsonRow.prix},
        ]
    };
    rows.push(row);
}


var dataFormatted = {
    cols: [
        { id: 'id', label: 'Id' },
        { id: 'nom', label: 'Nom' },
        { id: 'type', label: 'Type' },
        { id: 'quantity', label: 'Quantity' },
        { id: 'prix', label: 'Prix' },
    ],
    rows: rows
}

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataFormatted);
```

Comment: how can i convert it ? :'(

Comment: Edit the code that generate your JSON to make it generate in the correct format.

Comment: can i ! convert it with javascript ? am using spring boot in backend and i don't think i'll know how to edit them from there

Comment: Yes you can do it with JS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help