# How can I get a chart from a matrix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graph, charts

Hello everybody I am using AngularJS. I need to get a chart depends on the values of the matrix related to the choice selected.

**The HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-change="extractSubsities(selectedCity)" ng-options="item as item.name for item in cities track by item.name">
  </select>

  <select ng-show="selectedCity.subsities" ng-model="selectedSubCity" ng-change="extractSubsities(selectedSubCity)" ng-options="item2 as item2.name for item2 in selectedCity.subsities track by item2.name">
  </select>

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item3 in data track by item3.id">
      <!--but here I need to iterat the selectedSubCity too when I select DropDown 2-->
      <td>{{ item3.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item3.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item3.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ item3.qte}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

And this is my script json :

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.cities = [{
        name: "city A",
        elements: [{
          id: 'c01',
          name: 'name1',
          price: 15,
          qte: 10
        }, {
          id: 'c02',
          name: 'name2',
          price: 18,
          qte: 11
        }, {
          id: 'c03',
          name: 'name3',
          price: 11,
          qte: 14
        }],
        subsities: [{
          name: "sub A1",
          elements: [{
            id: 'sub01',
            name: 'nameSub1',
            price: 1,
            qte: 14
          }, {
            id: 'sub02',
            name: 'nameSub2',
            price: 8,
            qte: 13
          }, {
            id: 'sub03',
            name: 'nameSub3',
            price: 1,
            qte: 14
          }]
        }, {
          name: "sub A2",
          elements: [{
            id: 'ssub01',
            name: 'nameSsub1',
            price: 1,
            qte: 7
          }, {
            id: 'ssub02',
            name: 'nameSsub2',
            price: 8,
            qte: 1
          }, {
            id: 'ssub03',
            name: 'nameSsub3',
            price: 4,
            qte: 19
          }]
        }, {
          name: "sub A3",
          elements: [{
            id: 'sssub01',
            name: 'nameSssub1',
            price: 1,
            qte: 11
          }, {
            id: 'sssub02',
            name: 'nameSssub2',
            price: 2,
            qte: 15
          }, {
            id: 'sssub03',
            name: 'nameSssub3',
            price: 1,
            qte: 15
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        name: "city B",
        elements: [{
          id: 'cc01',
          name: 'name11',
          price: 10,
          qte: 11
        }, {
          id: 'cc02',
          name: 'name22',
          price: 14,
          qte: 19
        }, {
          id: 'cc03',
          name: 'name33',
          price: 11,
          qte: 18
        }]
      }, {
        name: "city C",
        elements: [{
          id: 'ccc01',
          name: 'name111',
          price: 19,
          qte: 12
        }, {
          id: 'ccc02',
          name: 'name222',
          price: 18,
          qte: 17
        }, {
          id: 'ccc03',
          name: 'name333',
          price: 10,
          qte: 5
        }]
      }];
      $scope.extractSubsities = function(itemSelected) {
        if (itemSelected && itemSelected.elements) {
          $scope.data = itemSelected.elements;
        }
      }

    });
```

I need to show a graph (chart) when I chose a city or a subcity. I need to show a graph deponds on the price and qte so I need to show two columns for each city or subcity. for example when I chose city A in DropDown 1 and sub A1 in the DropDown 2 to see a graph like :

[image]

Comment: What is your question? You can draw a chart using [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-introduction).

Comment: @fqhv how could do this please ?

Comment: Response for your comment on one of my answers: I'd like to help you out, but I don't see any specific questions here that I can answer. You can certainly check out [Angular-Google-Chart](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart), which is a project I maintain, but I only have time to respond to specific questions or requests for guidance.

Comment: As a warning, do not spam comments asking people to answer your questions. I just removed a ton of these across the site.

Answer (score 2):

Your question needs some clarification, but anyway, I'll try to answer it by listing three main points to keep in mind:

- You'll need to calculate the maximum value on every model change, `ngChange`.
- Use `ngStyle` to render the bars.
- CSS can handle pretty well this kind of charts.

I've crafted a little example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ChartController', function () {
    
    var max = 0;
    
    var cities = [
        {
            name   : 'Berlin',
            left   : 1000,
            right  : 5000,
            display: true
        },
        {
            name   : 'Lisbon',
            left   : 1000,
            right  : 500,
            display: true
        },
        {
            name   : 'London',
            left   : 2000,
            right  : 6000,
            display: true
        },
        {
            name   : 'Madrid',
            left   : 4000,
            right  : 200,
            display: true
        }
    ];
    
    this.cities = cities;
    
    this.percent = function (value) {
        
        return 100 * value / max + '%';
    };
    
    this.max = function () {
        
        max = cities.reduce(function (max, city) {
        
            return city.display ? Math.max(max, city.left, city.right) : max;

        }, -Infinity);
    };
    
    this.max();
});
```

```css
html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.l-display {
    padding: 5px;
}

.l-display label + label {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.l-chart {
    padding: 20px;
}

.l-chart ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.l-chart ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.l-chart li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.l-chart li + li {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.l-chart-bars {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

.l-chart-bars div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f1c40f;
}

.l-chart-bars div + div {
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.l-chart-label {
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartController as chart">
    <div class="l-display">
        <label ng-repeat="city in chart.cities">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="city.display" ng-change="chart.max()" />
            {{ city.name }}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="l-chart">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="city in chart.cities | filter:{display:true}">
                <div class="l-chart-bars">
                    <div ng-style="{height: chart.percent(city.left)}"></div>
                    <div ng-style="{height: chart.percent(city.right)}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="l-chart-label">{{ city.name }}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer I test it but don't work with me. can you please put it on https://plnkr.co/ please

Comment: Hmm But I need to keep my json like I did before for example I am using scope and in your code there no scope

Comment: @Abderrahim It's not a problem: `this` *might*, in some cases, be interchangeable with `$scope`. Try googling "angular this vs scope".

Comment: @falsarella not only scope in my example I use select and not check button I need to change graph depends on cities selected

Comment: I haven't done it exactly as you need to force you doing the rest, StackOverflow is not a place to get your tasks done but to share knowledge, therefore, try being more specific on your question and explain what is not working right now.

Comment: @coma you're right just I am new in AngularJS Thanks,

Comment: @falsarella I put scope instead of this but doesn't work with me
Any help please

Comment: That's sad, but try to adapt the answer to your needs and keep researching and troubleshooting your code.